# How to get all the records which are already checked in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the filter to get the items which are checked in check box but it is return only the current checked value in the drop down its not pulling the values that are already checked in the drop down list

Kendo drop down template for check box creation

```
.Template("<input type='checkbox' name='Chkfield' class='clsfield' )
```

Html

```
<div id="div" class="fieldBlock">
 <div id="ddl1" style="margin-left: 0px; display: none;" class="fieldBlock float-left">
 <input type="text" id="hdnfld" style="display: none;" value='' />
</div>
```

Jquery

```
var values = $(".Chkfield").filter(":checked");
var list = [];
for (var i = 0; i < values .length; i++) {
      finalselection+= values [i].nextSibling.wholeText + ",";
      list.push(values [i].value);
}
```

Comment: Could you add the related HTML?

Comment: may be this sample could help you out https://jsfiddle.net/aox6e4jy/

Comment: no i have a function where on clicking a checkbox that function gets called there i need to get all the previously checked values

Comment: can anybody help me out

Comment: It would be more helpful if you add the fully parsed HTML instead of the template, so we can see the structure.

Comment: The JS looks okay but without the context it's hard to say what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at checked selector of jquery.

[:CheckedSelector Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

**Description: Matches all elements that are checked or selected.**

below snippet has a simple Html structure and hope you can match it with yours, because
html format is not mentioned in question.

```js
// find elements
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
debugger
  $(".Chkfield:checked").each(function () {
            alert("Id: " + $(this).attr("id") + " Value: " + $(this).val());
        });
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello CheckBoxes</p>
    <input  type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" class="Chkfield">
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car"  class="Chkfield">
  <input  type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat" class="Chkfield">
  <br>
  
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: no i have a function where on clicking a checkbox that function gets called there i need to get all the previously checked values at a time into the variable so that using that length i can display them as comma seperated values in drop down

Comment: can you help me with one dummy example?

Comment: function onselect(e) {  var catTypes = $(".cbCareActTypeComp").filter(":checked");
                                  for (var i = 0; i < values .length; i++) {
      finalselection+= values [i].nextSibling.wholeText + ",";
      list.push(values [i].value);
} }  like this the function would be actually the drop down values are the listitems in unordered list i need to get al the list items at a time so that i can display them in drop down suppose if abc is a listitem and it is checked next i will search for xyz then i need to get previously selected abc and xyz as length 2

Comment: Can you make a simple fiddle for it?

Comment: Some things like what  this https://jsfiddle.net/aox6e4jy/ what I have commented on your question

Comment: http://demos.codexworld.com/multi-select-dropdown-list-with-checkbox-jquery/  it should be like jQuery MultiSelect With Search Option second one